# How to avoid refetching data if parameters don't change in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this function on a service that get details about a physical store :

```js
public getStoreDetails(storeName?: string, origin?:string): Observable<E2StoreFinderStore> {
    console.log('getStoreDetails', storeName, origin);
    const api = this.OCC.getUrl(`/stores/details/name/${storeName}`);
    let params = new HttpParams();
    return this.http
      .get<E2StoreFinderStore>(api, {
        responseType: 'json',
        params: params.append('fields', 'FULL').append('type', 'POS'),
      })
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleErrorService.handleError));
  }
```

this function is being called by 4 different components, but they are all using the same storeName, so they're basically fetching the same data from the API 4 times.
I was wondering how can I avoid refetching this data if the `storeName` parameter hasn't changed from the last time it was called.

For example, on the first time `getStoreDetails` is called it would store the data retrieved and on the subsequent times it is called if the `storeName` parameter is the same as before it would just return the stored data instead of running the API call.

Comment: I think you want to look into behavioursubjects or state-management like ngrx, the latter may be to complex depending on the size of your app. But essentially you fetch the data once and then store in a BehaviourSubject that will hold the data. [Here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-subject-example/) is a example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
dataLoaded: {[key: string]: E2StoreFinderStore }= {};
public getStoreDetails(storeName?: string, origin?:string): Observable<E2StoreFinderStore> {
  if(!this.dataLoaded[storeName]) {
    console.log('getStoreDetails', storeName, origin);
    const api = this.OCC.getUrl(`/stores/details/name/${storeName}`);
    let params = new HttpParams();
    return this.http
      .get<E2StoreFinderStore>(api, {
        responseType: 'json',
        params: params.append('fields', 'FULL').append('type', 'POS'),
      })
      .pipe(
        tap(res => { this.dataLoaded[storeName] = res }),
        catchError(this.handleErrorService.handleError)
      );
  } else {
    return new Observable((observer) => {
      observer.next(this.dataLoaded[storeName]);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
}
```

I provide some code at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3zz8uq

Comment: in your else branch, you should just `return of(this.dataLoaded[storeName])`